# What is the difference between tokio::spawn and tokio::task::spawn in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am making a web server capable of async operation using `tokio`.

I created a task via `tokio::spawn`, and I saw `tokio::task::spawn` working as well.

What is the difference between `tokio::sapwn` and `tokio::task::spawn`?

Answer (score 20):

Nothing. [`tokio::spawn()` is just a re-export of `tokio::task::spawn()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.31.0/src/tokio/lib.rs.html#546) for ease of use.